# deallocate memory of Node in Linked List

Tags: c++, memory, allocation

I am working on a singly linked list and I wanted to try another approach for my remove function algorithm for practice:

```
template<class T>
inline void LinkedList<T>::remove(T v)
{
    Node<T>** indirect = &head;
    while (*indirect && (*indirect)->value != v) {
        indirect = &((*indirect)->next);
    }
    *indirect = ((*indirect)->next);
}
```

all my nodes get created with through `new`. The last line simply changes the pointer to the following node. But I should free the memory `*indirect` was pointing to previously, right?

I changed my code so the node memory for the underlying node pointer gets freed. Also I keep track of the previous node in order to maintain the tail pointer:

```
template<class T>
inline void LinkedList<T>::remove(T v)
{
    Node<T>** indirect = &head;
    Node<T>* prev = nullptr;
    while (*indirect && (*indirect)->value != v) {
        prev = *indirect;
        indirect = &((*indirect)->next);
    }
    if (*indirect) {
        if (*indirect == tail) {
            tail = prev;
        }
        Node<T>* tmp = *indirect;
        *indirect = (*indirect)->next;
        delete tmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: For every `new`, there should be a `delete`. For every `new Type[n]`, there should be a `delete[]`. And once you get a first grip on that, let smart pointers do all the work for you and strive daily to *never* do manual memory management. That said, you're missing the `delete`, and you're missing the check for null before the final indirection (the case where the loop is exhausted and you never find the value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if the node was allocated with `new`, it should be deleted with `delete`.

That said, you're missing the node deletion, and more importantly the check against null before the final dereference. Your actual enumeration loop looks solid (grats on that; pointers-to-pointers aren't trivial for some people to grasp).

```
template<class T>
inline void LinkedList<T>::remove(T v)
{
    Node<T>** indirect = &head;
    while (*indirect && (*indirect)->value != v)
        indirect = &((*indirect)->next);

    if (*indirect)
    {
        Node<T> *tmp = *indirect;
        *indirect = tmp->next;
        delete tmp;
    }
}
```

Warning: Make sure your `Node` destructor doesn't do something stupid like try to delete it's linked chain.

---

**Managed list with `head` and `tail` pointers**

If you list has both a `head` and `tail` pointer to facilitate O(1) insertion on both ends, the algorithm is a little more complicated, but the complexity remains the same. You have to maintain a `prev` pointer during your enumeration loop, initially valued at `nullptr`, and walk it one-node-back from the primary iteration:

```
template<class T>
inline void LinkedList<T>::remove(T v)
{
    Node<T>** indirect = &head, *prev = nullptr;
    while (*indirect && (*indirect)->value != v)
    {
        prev = *indirect;
        indirect = &((*indirect)->next);
    }

    if (*indirect)
    {
        Node<T> *tmp = *indirect;

        // if the victim of the delete is also the tail
        //  then set it to the prior node pointer, which
        //  may be null if this was a single node list and
        //  both head and tail refer to the same node.
        if (tail == tmp)
            tail = prev;

        *indirect = tmp->next;
        delete tmp;
    }
}
```

The only thing left is to verify the machine above with the following conditions. What happens when...

- There are no nodes in the list that match?
- There is a single node in the list that matches?
- There a multiple nodes and the *first* node is a match?
- There are multiple nodes and the *last* node is a match?
- There are multiple nodes and some mid-node is a match?

The answers to each of these are worth the mental exercise and probably some paper, a pen/pencil, some boxes, and some arrows. Walk through the code above in each condition and see what happens. If everything seems right, it's probably solid. Of course, writing a stack of unit tests that fabricate lists for each of the conditions above and testing the function is always a solid idea.

Anyway, that's it.

Comment: I use a tail pointer. I would have to check if the node I just deleted was the tail so I can reset the tailpointer in my LinkedList class. Is there a way to avoid this (maybe not using a tailpointer at all... ? Would appending nodes give O(n) instead of O(1) though...

Comment: If you're going to manage a tail pointer as well, resetting it is a bit trickier. You must maintain a `prev` pointer in this code that refers to the prior node. There are special shortcuts that can be taken if you have ultimately control of member position (ie. if you *know* that `next` is the **first** member of the `Node` structure, which in your case it currently is *not*). But the simplest way is just to maintain a `prev`. I'll update the answer to include how to do that. Keep your tail-pointer. that O(1) end-insertion time is too beneficial to lose.